# BlocProvider not available within inherited widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver

Facing an issue with BlocProviders.

As I understand, a bloc should be accessible anywhere within the scope of inherited widgets.

I have an App class, which happens to be my core class, where I build my material App

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'E-Form',
    color: Color(0xFF44697D),
    home: BlocProvider(child: LaunchScreen()),
  );
}
```

Now I have the LaunchScreen class, here I am not using my BlocProvider, but I have wrapped LaunchScreen altogether in my App class with BlocProvider

```
class  LaunchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to second screen when tapped!
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now again in my third class, that is Home() class. I am trying to use my BlocProvider. Here I get an error saying the bloc is null

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    final bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Reduced Course Load'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF44697D),
      ),
      body: CustomWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

I am unable to figure out why this is null. The bloc is initialized perfectly if I initialize and print the bloc in LaunchScreen class. Does BlocProvider work only within a single class scope?

There's another error, I think my Navigator isn't working properly. For some reason, my Home() class constructor is getting recalled again. I am unable to fix the error in Navigator. An example would be great for me to understand a navigator.

Here is my flutter doctor results

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Please take a look, and share a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Give the full code , with the given code it is not clear what logic you have inside BlocProvider and BlocStepperProvider.

Comment: Check the documentation about InheritedWidget : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html  , it's only when you want to propagate information down the tree.

Comment: @ sreeramu, It is only BlocProvider, I forgot to refactor the name BlocStepperProvider with BlocProvider. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @diegoveloper, I understand that the information is going to be propagated down, I have gone through the documentation. My question is regarding why my bloc isn't accessible when I am propagating information down the tree.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use your `BlocProvider()` above the `MaterialApp` widget.

`Navigator` is a widget added by `MaterialApp` and when you call it to change a route it replaces the widget in `home:` property and hence replaces your `BlocProvider`.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocProvider(
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'E-Form',
      color: Color(0xFF44697D),
      home: LaunchScreen(),
    ),
  );
 }
```

Comment: Hi @chemamolins, I am still not sure why navigator will replace the entire home widget. Why is that required?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right. If you do a `push()` and not a `pushReplacement()` it is not replaced, just added to the stack of routes, but in anyway, the new route/page is parallel to the `home:` one. Your `BlocProvider()` is the root of the `home:` route, so you cann't find it from other routes. In your setup, give a look to the Widget Inspector tree. You will see that your `BlocProvider` and your `Home()` are in different branches. Have you tried to place the `BlocProvider()` above the `MaterialApp`?

Answer (score 1):

ensure that u add this flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1 to dependencies in ur pubspec.yaml file
then add this .. import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

Answer (score 0):

Also you could pass your bloc to screen "Home" and there wrap your Scaffold in BlocProvider.value(yourBlocInstance). BTW, this lets you put initial providing your bloc with BlocProvider(create: (context) => YourBloc()) under MaterialApp and navigation would not break it.